# Disabling a triggered WebJob in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

If I remove the `settings.job` file from a triggered WebJob folder, will that effectively stop it from running again until I put the `settings.job` file back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when removed, default settings will be provided.   depending on your trigger type, for instance if cron scheduler, then it won't start up again.   best way is to experiment how it behaves yourself.